# Column Data into Rows by Employee Identifier

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hoping someone can help out.

I have employees who have dependents. The company pays a fee for each dependent to cover life insurance. The data for this is exported.

The table looks like this:

[image]

However, I need end result to look like this:

[image]

Comment: This link might be useful: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/681-excel-change-columns-to-rows.html

Comment: Can you add the version of Excel and windows?

Answer (score -3):

you can easily do that using PivotTable in Excel

Edit :
here is an example from Microsoft on how to use pivot table

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576

Comment: I've tried every variation I can think of to get the end result but something not working out

Comment: This answer does not explain how to do anything. You should add example code and a proper description of how you would do it.

Comment: well pivottable are pretty straightforward, select all your data including headings, then insert - pivottable and organize data as needed.

Comment: is it possible to post your spreadsheet?